# Thirty dollars is/ are

Tags: verb-agreement, subjects

I know that amounts of money are followed by a singular verb. But l am not sure if we can use a singular or plural verb in the following sentence:

Thirty dollars is/are found in the drawer.

I guess we can use "are" because we are talking about a number of dollars. But what if the speaker was talking about an amount of money?

Any help?

Comment: This belongs on ELL.SE.

Comment: Measure expressions like _thirty dollars, ten days, five miles etc_., are plural in form, but the quantity or measure they denote can be conceptualised as a single abstract entity and thus can override the plural form in determining the form of the verb. Sometimes the override is obligatory, but in this case, it is optional though often preferred.

Comment: Bill J: So the two forms can be used in this construction according to the speaker's concept of the subject, thirty dollars.